# OCaml Ctypes and allocating a pointer to a type

Tags: ocaml, ctypes

I'm trying to call some C code from OCaml where I need to supply an allocated pointer to my type `yaml_parser_t`. But I'm not sure how I should be allocating a valid pointer. The example code is below.

Ideally I'd like to not have to supply a concrete implementation for `yaml_parser_t` as well, since I don't need to inspect it's internals, just pass it into and out of various functions. I was initially following the time_t example from [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/foreign-function-interface.html#pointers-and-arrays) but they seem to be using the `time` function to allocate which I don't have here.

Sorry for the confused explanation.

```
open PosixTypes;;
open Ctypes;;
open Foreign;;

type yaml_parser_t = unit;;
let yaml_parser_t : yaml_parser_t typ = void;;

(* To get it working in utop, specify the name of the library *)
let libyaml = Dl.(dlopen ~filename:"libyaml.dylib" ~flags:[RTLD_NOW]);;

let init = foreign "yaml_parser_initialize" (ptr yaml_parser_t @-> returning int);;

let make =
    let p_ptr = allocate yaml_parser_t (from_voidp yaml_parser) in
    let _ = init p_ptr in
    p_ptr;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to allocate something you need to know its size. In the `libyaml` library the `yaml_parser_t` type is not opaque, so the most correct way to work with such type, would be to declare it in ctypes as a struct and describe all its fields. In that case, you can just use `allocate` function to create the value. But, I will understand you, if you will refuse to do it. The `yaml_parser_t` structure is enormous and life is too short. Since, there is no way to discover the size of the structure in the runtime, you need either write the c stub function, or just harcode it in your library. The latter is not that bad, as one may think, since the size should only change on major version changes, as `yaml_parser_t` is explicitly made non-opaque, and is considered a part of the interface.

### Allocating data for abstract values

There're two functions in ctypes that allows to allocate memory, namely `allocate` and `allocate_n`. The former requires an instance of the allocated value. Since our type is abstract, we will use the latter, as it doesn't require us to provide a value.

First we need to describe an abstract type. We need to provide only three values: name, size and alignment. Name is easy, it can be an arbitrary string. Size and alignment are known for sure only for the C compiler. The easiest way is to write a small program, that prints them using `sizeof` and `__alignof__` compile time instructions. And then copy-paste the output to your `ml` code. If you find this solution to dirty, then you can write two primitive c functions, that will return this values at runtime. So, suppose, you've retrived this values, then we can now create a type for `yaml_parser_t`:

```
let size = 100
let alignment = 0

let yaml_parser_t : unit abstract typ =
  abstract ~name:"yaml_parser_t" ~size ~alignment
```

Now you can use `yaml_parser_t` to allocate memory:

```
let allocate_yaml_parser () : unit abstract ptr =
  allocate_n yaml_parser_t ~count:1
```

And then you can try to allocate it:

```
# let p = allocate_yaml_parser ();;
val p : unit Ctypes.abstract Ctypes.ptr = (yaml_parser_t*) 0x10156d0
```

Next, you can cast it to void, or to some other type and pass it to your stubs.

P.S. The `libyaml` interface is rather odd, that is the root of the problem. The `yaml_parser_t` type should be opaque, and there should be provided a function, that creates it. But, unfortunately, we have what we have.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my answer, clearly I should have looked over the code more closely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really didn't want to have to describe the whole structure in OCaml, since it is large and complicated, and I don't need to know about it's structure to use it.

How would I go about hardcoding the value for the size of `yaml_parser_t`?Is it a matter of using something like `Buffer.create` and passing in the calculated size? Can I safely cast that to a type of `yaml_parser_t`?

Comment: @lambda_foo Ctypes has added quite a lot of features since Real World OCaml came out. I think some of these features (in particular C stub generation) let you do what you want. I would suggest asking the ctypes mailing list (ctypes@lists.ocaml.org).

Comment: @lambda_foo, I've update the post with instructions on how to allocate memory.

Comment: @LeoWhite, I doubt that stub generation will be of any use here.

Comment: @ivg I believe latest ctypes includes stub generation for querying the size of structs (essentially automatically creating your suggested C program for querying the struct size)